# reduce window scroll function to a simple if statement

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'd like to be able to trigger an event if the scrollTop position is more than 800px. We all know this can be accomplished by wrapping the if statement in a window scroll function, like so...

```
         $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
             // do something
           }
         });
```

Can I do this without tying it to a window scroll function?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
           if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
             // just do it
           }
```

Alright, be gentle.

Comment: No you can't there needs to be something to know that the window is scrolling. That's the $(window).scroll handler

Comment: `$(window).scroll()` is an event handler - that is something that happens when an event takes place.  In this case you are saying "run this code when the window is scrolled".  Without that your if statement would execute just once, and never again for the life of the page.

Comment: Well, I've read that it's a memory/CPU hog for one thing, and second, I want something to exec only once.

Comment: @Archer, OK, Bam, thanks for reminding me. I tied it to .one('scroll',function(){ and that solves half of my problems right there. Still though, there must be an alternate way of saying, "If the user is over 800px down the page somewhere, do this."

Comment: No - what you have done is just run the if statement the very first time the user scrolls, regardless of how much they scroll.  If they scroll a little bit then and then lots the code won't run the 2nd time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't unless you call it from something else, a click handler or something.

Any reason why you don't want to bind to the scroll event?

Edit::

For the sake completeness, here's another less-cpu-intensive way, just use a time-stamp.

```
var dt = new Date();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    if(now - dt < 1000) return; //1000 === 1 second
    //do stuff
    dt = now;
});
```